# how can I avoid syntax errors for unexpected variables?

Tags: php, parsing, web-deployment

Having some issues parsing this batch of php to send form data to my AWS RDS database. I have followed a few tutorials but I seem to end up in the same place.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('accountuserdb.cyietmcjutfg.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com','redact','redact')

$Email = $_POST('email');
$Username = $_POST('username');
$Userpass = $_POST('password');

$sql = "INSERT INTO useraccounts (Email,Username,Userpass) VALUES ('$Name','$Username','$Userpass')";

header("refresh:2; url="success.html");

?>
```

I am a little confused as to why I am receiving the parse error? outdated syntax maybe?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you access array elements with `[]`, not `()`

so you have to write

```
$Email = $_POST['email'];
```

instead of

```
$Email = $_POST('email');
```

and make sure to properly escape the values with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php